# Websphere Portal 8, Spring 4, JPA - No Transactional EntityManager available

Tags: spring, jpa, websphere, portal, transactional

When trying to save an entity to the database (sql server) I'm getting the exception:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional
>   EntityManager available

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="OrchardUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl </provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mydatasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.bbb.entity.BaseEntity</class>
        <class>com.bbb.entity.Audit</class>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sqlserver" />        
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

application-config.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<<view resolver here. removed for space>>

<jee:jndi-lookup id=" wasDataSource "
                jndi-name="jdbc/mydatasource"
                cache="true"
                resource-ref="true"
                lookup-on-startup="false"
                proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="OrchardUnit"/>
</bean>     

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

I have a simple entity and a service class. I mark the service with `@Transactional` but when I try to save I get the exception above. I am able to read the database but not write.

When I take the same setup and put it in a simple web application and deploy to WebSphere 8 I am able to save when I hit the simple servlet.

I'm doing this on WebSphere Portal 8 running on WebSphere 8 with Spring 4.1.6 and the OpenJPA provider built into WebSphere (I also tried with Hibernate and had the same problem).

Anyone have any thoughts? I don't want to go to UserTransactions as container managed is easier.

Top of exception:

> [5/13/15 11:22:47:235 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:236 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:236 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy279.persist(Unknown Source)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:237 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at com.???.service.AbstractService.create(AbstractService.java:31)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:237 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at com.???.service.AuditService.create(AuditService.java:19)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:237 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at com.???.portlet.controller.ViewController.SpringJSP(ViewController.java:31)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:237 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:237 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:238 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:238 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:238 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:238 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:369)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:242 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:356)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:242 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleRender(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:296)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:242 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:764)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:242 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:536)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:242 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:483)
>   [5/13/15 11:22:47:243 EDT] 0000004c SystemErr     R     at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:222)

Comment: Can you the stack trace of the failure?  It would be useful to see where that is occurring relative to the transactional bean and the rest of the WebSphere Application Server processing.

Comment: I didn't find a solution so I removed Spring and Hibernate and went with Stateless EJB and CDI (although could not inject into portlet).